# Spacing a centered text above an image

Tags: html, css

I'm setting a text centered above an image but i don't know how to make it looks normally stretched all above the image or making spaces between the texts so it may look approciate.

[image: Click here to view how it looks like]

[image: Click here to view how i want it to look like]

```
 container1,
  .container2 {
    position: relative;
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 1.7em;
    color: #fff;
    font-stretch: expanded;
    font-size: 1.5em;
    letter-spacing: 2.5px;
    font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    text-shadow: -1px -1px 0 #333, 1px -1px 0 #333, -1px 1px 0 #333,
      1px 1px 0 #333;
  }

  .container1 > img,
  .container2 > img {
    height: auto;
    width: 70%;
  }

  .centeredtext {
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  }

     <div class="container1">
      <a href="maintenanceservices.html"><img id="imgsize" src="imgs/mechanicservice.jpg" alt="services"></a>
      <div class="centeredtext">
        <h3>Maintenances Services</h3>
      </div>
    </div>
     <div class="container2"> 
      <a href="sparepartsshop.html"><img id="imgsize" src="imgs/carengine.jpg" alt="spare parts"></a>
      <div class="centeredtext">
        <h3>Spare-parts Shop</h3>
      </div>
```

Comment: I think you have shared the same image twice. Is there a difference in these 2 images?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Changing

```
  .centeredtext {
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  }
```

to

```
  .centeredtext {
    white-space: nowrap;
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  }
```

should force the text to stay in one line

Answer (score 0):

Give this a try:

```
.centeredtext {
 position: absolute;
 display: block;

 top: 50%;
 transform: translate(0%, -50%);
 width: 100%;

 margin: auto;
 margin-left: auto;
 margin-right: auto;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

For me, replacing

> container1

by

> container2

worked.
Try this:

```
 <div class="container2">
  <a href="maintenanceservices.html"><img id="imgsize" src="imgs/mechanicservice.jpg" alt="services"></a>
  <div class="centeredtext">
    <h3>Maintenances Services</h3>
  </div>
</div>
 <div class="container2"> 
  <a href="sparepartsshop.html"><img id="imgsize" src="imgs/carengine.jpg" alt="spare parts"></a>
  <div class="centeredtext">
    <h3>Spare-parts Shop</h3>
  </div>
```

Though this happened because you missed adding "." before "container1" in your css. Doing so will make this work.
Try using the below css:

```
.container1,
  .container2 {
    position: relative;
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 1.7em;
    color: #fff;
    font-stretch: expanded;
    font-size: 1.5em;
    letter-spacing: 2.5px;
    font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    text-shadow: -1px -1px 0 #333, 1px -1px 0 #333, -1px 1px 0 #333,
      1px 1px 0 #333;
  }

  .container1 > img,
  .container2 > img {
    height: auto;
    width: 70%;
  }

  .centeredtext {
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  }
```

Comment: I think that is because he missed the . for the class in his css in the question.